# TextView() null when changed from Activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

In this android application, I had converted an activity to fragment, while inactivity no exception had been raised but when it is converted to fragment it is throwing an exception.

Here is the showtime() method in AlarmTimePickerDialog class:

```
    public void showTimeLeft(int hour, int minute) {
    if (getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview_timepickerdialog_timeleft);
        AlarmTime time = new AlarmTime(hour, minute);
        textView.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.all_time_left, time.getHoursLeft(), time.getMinutesLeft()));
    }
}
```

Here is what the log

```
2020-06-23 15:16:42.586 9082-9082/com.vikaskonaparthi.time E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vikaskonaparthi.time, PID: 9082
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.vikaskonaparthi.time.dialogs.AlarmTimePickerDialog.showTimeLeft(AlarmTimePickerDialog.java:44)
    at com.vikaskonaparthi.time.dialogs.TimePickerDialogFragment$1.onShow(TimePickerDialogFragment.java:52)
    at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1413)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Here is the fragment which I am using as a tab in my app

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements
    IntervalDialogFragment.IntervalDialogListener,
    NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.NumberOfAlarmsDialogListener,
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

SwitchCompat onOffSwitch;
ListView alarmsListView;
TextView intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView;
TextView numberOfAlarmsTextView;
TextView firstAlarmTextView;
TextView timeLeftTextView;
LinearLayout firstAlarmLayout;
LinearLayout intervalLayout;
LinearLayout numberOfAlarmsLayout;
AlarmsListHelper alarmsListHelper;
SharedPreferencesHelper sharPrefHelper;
TimerManager timerManager;
AlarmParams alarmParams;
BroadcastReceiver timeLeftReceiver;
private final String LOG_TAG = Fragment1.class.getSimpleName();

final int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 45;
final float DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION = 2f;  // number of alarms, first alarm, interval values text size is larger than text around them

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
    alarmsListView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listview_main_alarmslist);
    onOffSwitch = (SwitchCompat) root.findViewById(R.id.switch_main);
    intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview_main_interval);
    numberOfAlarmsTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview_main_numberofalarms);
    firstAlarmLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.layout_main_firstalarm);
    firstAlarmTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview_main_firstalarm_time);
    timeLeftTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview_main_timeleft);
    intervalLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.layout_main_interval);
    numberOfAlarmsLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.layout_main_numberofalarms);

    sharPrefHelper = new SharedPreferencesHelper(getActivity());
    sharPrefHelper.printAll();

    alarmParams = sharPrefHelper.getParams();
    timerManager = new TimerManager(getActivity());
    alarmsListHelper = new AlarmsListHelper(getActivity(), alarmsListView);

    showFirstAlarmTime(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);

    showInterval(sharPrefHelper.getIntervalStr());
    showNumberOfAlarms(sharPrefHelper.getNumberOfAlarmsStr());
    onOffSwitch.setChecked(sharPrefHelper.isAlarmTurnedOn());

    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);

    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            alarmParams.turnedOn = isChecked;
            if (isChecked) {
                checkNotificationPolicy();
                checkOverlayPermission();
                timerManager.startSingleAlarmTimer(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toMillis());
                showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_turned_on_toast));
                sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlreadyRangAlarms(0);
            } else {
                timerManager.cancelTimer();
                showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_turned_off_toast));
            }
            alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
            showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
            sharPrefHelper.setAlarmState(isChecked);
        }
    });

    intervalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntervalDialogFragment dialog = new IntervalDialogFragment();
            Bundle intervalBundle = new Bundle();
            intervalBundle.putString(IntervalDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_INTERVAL, sharPrefHelper.getIntervalStr());
            dialog.setArguments(intervalBundle);
            dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), IntervalDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    numberOfAlarmsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment dialog = new NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment();
            Bundle numberOfAlarmsBundle = new Bundle();
            numberOfAlarmsBundle.putString(NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_NUMBER_OF_ALARMS, sharPrefHelper.getNumberOfAlarmsStr());
            dialog.setArguments(numberOfAlarmsBundle);
            dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    firstAlarmLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle timePickerBundle = new Bundle();
            timePickerBundle.putInt(TimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_HOUR, sharPrefHelper.getHour());
            timePickerBundle.putInt(TimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_MINUTE, sharPrefHelper.getMinute());

            TimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerDialogFragment();

            timePicker.setArguments(timePickerBundle);
            timePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), TimePickerDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    return root;


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
    timeLeftReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {  //i.e. every minute
                showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
            }
        }
    };
    getActivity().registerReceiver(timeLeftReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}



@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (timeLeftReceiver != null) {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(timeLeftReceiver);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PrefActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onIntervalChanged(String intervalStr) {
    showInterval(intervalStr);
    alarmParams.interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalStr);
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setInterval(intervalStr);
}

@Override
public void onNumberOfAlarmsChanged(String numberOfAlarmsStr) {
    showNumberOfAlarms(numberOfAlarmsStr);
    alarmParams.numberOfAlarms = Integer.parseInt(numberOfAlarmsStr);
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlarms(numberOfAlarmsStr);
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    AlarmTime alarmTime = new AlarmTime(hour, minute);
    alarmParams.firstAlarmTime = alarmTime;
    showFirstAlarmTime(alarmTime.toString());
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
    sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlreadyRangAlarms(0);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setTime(alarmTime);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void resetTimerIfTurnedOn() {
    if (onOffSwitch.isChecked()) {
        timerManager.resetSingleAlarmTimer(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toMillis());
        showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_reset_toast));
    }
}

private void showInterval(String interval) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.main_interval, interval);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION), wholeTitle.indexOf(interval), interval.length() + 1, 0);
    intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showNumberOfAlarms(String numberOfAlarms) {
    int numberOfAlarmsInt = Integer.parseInt(numberOfAlarms);
    String wholeTitle = this.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.main_number_of_alarms, numberOfAlarmsInt, numberOfAlarmsInt);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(numberOfAlarms),
            numberOfAlarms.length() + 1, 0);
    numberOfAlarmsTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showFirstAlarmTime(String firstAlarmTime) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.main_firstalarm_time, firstAlarmTime);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) - 1,
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) + firstAlarmTime.length(), 0);
    firstAlarmTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showTimeLeft(AlarmParams alarmParams) {
    AlarmTime alarmTime = alarmParams.firstAlarmTime;
    timeLeftTextView.setText(getString(R.string.all_time_left, alarmTime.getHoursLeft(), alarmTime.getMinutesLeft()));
    if (alarmParams.turnedOn) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.primary));
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.main_disabled_textcolor));
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time left: "+alarmTime.getHoursLeft() + ":" + alarmTime.getMinutesLeft());
}

private void checkNotificationPolicy() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * needed for Android Q: on some devices activity doesn't show from fullScreenNotification without
 * permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 */
private void checkOverlayPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) && (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getActivity()))) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is alarmTimePickerDialog class which is throwing an exception

```
public class AlarmTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

public AlarmTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute,
                             boolean is24HourView) {
    super(context, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
}

@Override
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    super.onTimeChanged(view, hourOfDay, minute);
    showTimeLeft(hourOfDay, minute);
}

@Override
public void setCustomTitle(View customTitleView) {
    if (getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) { //title is displayed in portrait orientation only
        super.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);
    }
}

public void showTimeLeft(int hour, int minute) {
    if (getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview_timepickerdialog_timeleft);
        AlarmTime time = new AlarmTime(hour, minute);
        textView.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.all_time_left, time.getHoursLeft(), time.getMinutesLeft()));
    }
}
}
```

Here is xml file of partial_timepicker_dialog_title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_timepickerdialog_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/main_textcolor"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/timepicker_dialog_title"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_timepickerdialog_timeleft"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="@color/primary"
    />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please put onCreateView() code

Comment: sorry please put code of AlarmTimePickerDialog

Comment: Yes i had edited

Comment: where you get this view `R.id.textview_timepickerdialog_timeleft`. I mean inflating

Comment: Edited again with xml file

Comment: your xml file should be inflated/ added inside the AlarmTimePickerDialog class

Comment: ya it is like that,the app is working as a activity very well and good but this is after i changed it to fragment

Comment: I cannot understand that can you help me

Comment: How to inflate text view

Comment: @Vikaskonaparthi I think you need to add a getView Method